# Replace the top 10 values in numpy

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

Is there any easy way to replace the top 10 values with 1 and the rest of them with zeros? I have found that numpy argpartition can give me a new array with the index but I haven't been able to easily use it in the original array?
Can anyone help?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you need to sort it? Just put 10 ones and rest of them zeros.

Comment: Are you sure that your goal doesn't work best with masks, by the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it using `np.sort` to find the 10th largest value, and then use `np.where` to flag the array.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(30)

a_10 = np.sort(a)[-10]

a_new = np.where(a >= a_10, 1, 0)

print(a)     # Print the original
print(a_new) # Print the boolean array
```

**EDIT:** A single-line, in-place operation is thus

```
a = np.where(a >= np.sort(a)[-10], 1, 0)
```

**EDIT2:** The answer can be extended to 2D. I made a 6x6 matrix, where I flag per row the 3 largest values with a 1.

```
# 2D example, save top3 per 
a = np.random.rand(6, 6)

a_3 = np.sort(a, axis=1)[:,-3]
a_new = np.where(a >= a_3[:,None], 1, 0)

print(a)
print(a_new)
```

Comment: @Petar. You can overwrite it of course by assigning to `a`, rather than `a_new`, but now you can print it and check it.

Comment: Technically, this still isn't affecting the original array. You are just linking a new array to an existing pointer.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis. But if I assign to `a` again, like in the edit, then the garbage collection cleans up the original memory, because its reference count equals zero. So in that case the original is affected.

Comment: Thank you Chiel :). This works perfectly for 1d array and also very intuitive. How can I do the same with 2d array where we sort in axis=1?

Comment: @Chiel, in that case, would you consider the following to be "in-place": `a = np.array([1, 2]); a = np.array([1, 2, 3])` ?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis. I agree with you, it is not in place. Your method has probably one array copy less. Did you benchmark our methods against each other?

Comment: @Chiel, I see your code is 20% faster. But I haven't tested memory implications. If python garbage collection is really so efficient, your way is definitely better :).

Comment: @jp_data_analysis. Thanks for testing. It is not straightforward to understand why, though.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way. It is an in-place solution. For a new array, see [@Chiel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664800/9209546).

```
import numpy as np

n = 50

a = np.random.rand(n)
args = np.argsort(a)
a[args[-10:]] = 1
a[args[:-10]] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `argpartition` to find the 39th position. Use the index to do selection.

```
from numpy.random import shuffle
a = np.arange(50)
shuffle(a)
b = np.argpartition(a, 39)  
c = a.copy()
c[b[-10:]] = 1  # a[b[-10:]] = 1 in place
c[b[:-10]] = 0  # a[b[:-10]] = 0 in place
```

Demo

```
a[b[-10:]]
array([42, 40, 48, 46, 43, 41, 44, 49, 47, 45])
```

With the index you can do it either in place or create a new array like I did. (If you want to do it in place, just do it on `a` rather than `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way could be using np.argsort() twice and then set the values to zero or 1

```
a = np.random.rand(6, 6)
rank1=a.argsort()
rank2=rank1.argsort()
a_new[rank2>=3]=1
a_new[rank2<3]=0
```